# Vuejs v-html on an element containing other element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Basically I want to render some html (some li elements) inside an ul to populate it, but the ul also have some list element defined in it I want to render.

```
<ul v-html="getList()">
    <li>Last list element I need to render after the elements returned from getList</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any simple way to do that ?

Comment: Could you paste the code of the li elements that you want to render?

Comment: You can use `ref` to access the `ul` html element & render the element https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

Answer (score 1):

`v-html` replaces the `innerHTML` of the tag, so any slot content is lost.  From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML):

> The contents... will be replaced

A workaround for `<li>` elements `v-html` is trickier than it seems because you can't apply it to anything but a `<ul>` or the HTML will be invalid and `<template>` can't use `v-html`.  A wrapper slot component doesn't help much either unless you use a render function with a custom parser but it seems like overkill.

A couple of easier options:

- Append the slotted `<li>` inside of `getList()`
- Use 2 `<ul>`:

```html
<ul v-html="getList()"></ul>
<ul>
  <li>asdf</li>
</ul>
```